# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'JSONField' in django 3.0.5

Tags: django

I am trying add a model in my app like this:

```
class WarehouseTablePreferences(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    column_preferences = models.JSONField(default=dict)
```

and in the app I have:

```
Django==3.0.5
django-cors-headers==3.2.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
```

but its still giving me the following error:

```
 File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend copy/users/models.py", line 407, in <module>
    class WarehouseTablePreferences(models.Model):
  File "/Users/rahulsharma/PycharmProjects/Trakkia-Backend copy/users/models.py", line 409, in WarehouseTablePreferences
    column_preferences = models.JSONField(default=dict)
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'JSONField'
```

Comment: You can try to import from `from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField`. Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that JSONField (in the form that you use it) has been introduced only from Django 3.1 : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/3.1/